# How to add a "Recent Applications" stack to the Dock?

Tags: dock, monterey

The Dock on my macOS Monterey machine does not show a stack of recent **applications**. It **does** show "Recents" but these are recent **documents**.

System Preferences > Dock & Menu Bar > Show recent applications **is checked** but there is no corresponding stack of recent applications in the Dock (which has been killed and restarted since ticking that checkbox).

**How can I add a "Recent Applications" stack to my Dock?**

Comment: It's not a stack, they just hang around in the dock for a while after you quit [no idea how long]. There's a list in the  menu which seems to have a permanent count of last 10? apps used.

Comment: @Tetsujin Nope. Not on my system. Hence my question.

Comment: Nope to which ?

Comment: @Tetsujin "they just hang around in the dock for a while after you quit" ←Nope to that.

Comment: @Tetsujin In another fine example of "Just be proximate to people who can provide technical support, and your problem will go away" some time after me last comment "they just hang around the dock for a while" started working! :D So thank you!